Dynamically refering to max and min values in a color scale in ggplot2
I am creating a figure with a gradient fill scale. The values range from negative to positive, and I want white to represent 0.
I already know how to do this using scale_fill_gradientn, using scales::rescale on the min, 0, and max values for the scales to properly match.
v <- cbind.data.frame( comparison = c("c1","c2","c3","c4"), 
log2FoldChange = c(0.1608255, 0.2741105, -0.3197456, -0.2285475))

ggplot(v, aes(x=log2FoldChange, y=comparison, fill=log2FoldChange)) +
     geom_col() +
     scale_fill_gradientn( values= scales::rescale( c(min(v$log2FoldChange),0,max(v$log2FoldChange)) ),
                           colors = c("deepskyblue","white","firebrick1")) +
     theme_minimal() +
     theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
     labs(x="log2 Fold Change", y="Comparison")


However, in this way, I have to refer to the original dataframe's variable to get the min/max. This can be annoying if I have to repeat a similar plot using a slightly different variable or other datasets.
I have tried referring dynamically to the value on the x-axis with
values= scales::rescale( c(min(.x),0,max(.x)) )
> Error: object '.x' not found

or
values= scales::rescale( c(min(~.x),0,max(~.x)) )
> Error in min(~.x) : invalid 'type' (language) of argument

but neither worked.
The one I used it previously to modify secondary axes like:
 scale_y_continuous(name = "Density", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x*50, name = "Counts")) +

I couldn't find anywhere a way for ggplot commands to refer dynamically to the variables used for x and y-axes, as well as other ones.
Is that even possible with current ggplot coding?

Apologies for linking to my own stuff, but please see the following piece for centering divergent colour scales at 0: https://github.com/teunbrand/ggplot_tricks?tab=readme-ov-file#setting-midpoints-in-divergent-scales

Thanks.
It woks somewhat, but rescale_mid tries to scale the values with the same range on both sides of the 0:
> scales::rescale_mid(v$log2FoldChange, mid=0) [1] 0.7514898 0.9286384 0.0000000 0.1426104
> v$log2FoldChange [1]  0.1608255  0.2741105 -0.3197456 -0.2285475
> scales::rescale_mid(c(-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1), mid=0) [1] 0.000 0.125 0.250 0.375 0.500 0.625 0.750
`
As you can see, the lowest value is rescaled to 0, the mid (0) is rescaled to 0.5, but the highest value is not rescaled to 1. (I don't know how to format code here)
